Rating this old physics manual for engineering
I found this old physics manual for engineering it's no doubt outdated, but I like the overall formatting and short nature of the book. Is there anything in it outdated and now found inaccurate?

You omitted the link, but here are some general observations on this topic.
The great advances in physics that have occurred in the last ~50 years have happened in fields involving neutrinos, quarks, electroweak unification, supernovas, the Hubble constant/cosmology, black hole thermodynamics, gravitational waves and high-temperature superconduction. Within this list, only high-temperature superconductivity impinges on any everyday engineering field.
This means that a short book on physics for engineers, even if 50 years old, would still be worth reading and understanding.

https://www.survivorlibrary.com/library/analytical_mechanics_for_students_of_physics_and_engineering_1913.pdf link is here
